# Find the cardinality of the set

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $A = \{0,1,2,3\}$.
>   Find the cardinality of the set
>   $$\left\{f\mid f:A\rightarrow A\land f(x) = ax+b\land a,b\in A\land\text{$f$ is one-to-one}\right\}$$

The only method i can think of is to list out all the possible functions exhaustively.

What are the better methods?

Comment: Sometimes, you just start listing out all possible functions exhaustively, and it quickly gives you ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=0$, then we are not going to have a injection, hence $a>0$.

That is $f$ is an increasing function.

Hence we must have $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$.

That is 
$f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since f is an injection, a cannot be 0. 
Since f is into A, 3a + b is in A.
The only values for nonzero a and any b in A for which
3a + b is in A are a = 1, b = 0.